# Get the maximum of the sum in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in SQL Server

```
SELECT cod_producto, SUM(D.cantidad) AS totalVenta
FROM DETALLE_FACTURAS D
GROUP BY cod_producto
ORDER BY totalVenta DESC;
```

Output:

```
COD_PRODUCTO    TOTALVENTA
--------------------------
  P0003             22 
  P0005             21
  P0005             24
  P0005             27
```

How can I get the maximum of the sum of the total alias?

Comment: Please use formatted text, not images.

Comment: *How can I get the maximum of the sum of the total allias* Add `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript? and css?

Comment: @DaleK SQL Server

Comment: And please add some sample data and expected results to clarify what you mean because I don't know what "total allias" means.

Comment: So you want the result of "27"?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP (1) cod_producto, SUM(D.cantidad) as totalVenta
FROM DETALLE_FACTURAS D
GROUP BY cod_producto
ORDER BY totalVenta DESC;
```